Why when i try to get an array of data that i send from axios, the list split into multiple values (views.py)
I try to send a list of data from frontend via axios and recieve it in views.py with django.
The style of a data that I send:
[{ nameDetail: "1", valueDetail: "3" }, { nameDetail: "2", valueDetail: "4" }]

And this is when I console.log before I pass the value to axios:
Array(2) 0: {nameDetail: 'Size', valueDetail: '2oz'}, 1: {nameDetail: 'Color', valueDetail: 'White'}, length: 2, [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Request with axios:
const { data } = await axios.post(
      `http://localhost:8000/api/products/product/add/`,
      {
        name: name,
        brand: brand,
        category: category,
        description: description,
        badge: badge,
        price: price,
        discount: discount,
        countInStock: countInStock,
        images: images,
        details: details, <===== this is the data that i have a problem with
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userLogin.token}`,
        },
      }
    )

But when I fetch it in views.py with print(request.data) the data transform:
<QueryDict: {'name': ['Electronic'], 'brand': ['ez'], 'category': ['Juices'], 'description': ['azea'], 'badge': ['promos'], 'price': ['22'], 'discount': ['2'], 'countInStock': ['2'], 'details[0][nameDetail]': ['Size'], 'details[0][valueDetail]': ['2oz'], 'details[1][nameDetail]': ['Color'], 'details[1][valueDetail]': ['White'], 'images[]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: S33ef534d442d4a1d82ce7f52821f391aX (1).webp (image/webp)>]}>

Why is this happening and how can I can pass a list of data to the backend and loop through it?
Thank you.

JavaScript Arrays are Objects hence even when you console.log them, you will get an Object with keys as Array element indices and values as actual Array elements.
To pass this over the wire as an array  [1] the best option is to encode as JSON using JSON.stringify.
details: JSON.stringify(details), <===== problem solved!

[1] By array I mean data that has array representation [•••] which we all recognize.

i try it and get this :
['[{"nameDetail":"Size","valueDetail":"100ml"},{"nameDetail":"Color","valueDetail":"white"}]']
i try to loop through it and add to my db
details = data.getlist('details')
print(type details[0])
for d in details[0]:
detail = Properties.objects.create(
product = product,
name = d["nameDetail"],
value = d["valueDetail"],
)
but nothing happened and i can't acces the values and the type of data of details[0] is string

That particular value is actually stringified —it is turned into a sequence of characters. You must decode that JSON character sequence to a python object using json.loads(details) from the python inbuilt json library. Just import json.

I Found the solution, it was just to transform the data on the client like this answer suggested.
details: JSON.stringify(details),

And on the server, I transformed the data using:
import json

details = data['details']
list = json.loads(details) # <==== transform the data into list of dictionaries
for d in list:
    detail = Properties.objects.create(
        product = product,
        name = d["nameDetail"],
        value = d["valueDetail"],
    )


That was not a comment, that was an answer. Welcome to [so].
